# Is this variable a candidate for the `global` keyword?

Tags: php

I have this code (in Floral.php) that I was given to me as a shopping cart app which works on one (1) web page; I had to dismember it because of the structure of my web pages and now I'm trying to put it back together so it works with multiple web pages (files):

```
       <?php

session_start();

define("PRODUCTCODE", 0);
define("PRODUCTNAME", 1);
define("QUANTITY", 2);
define("PRICE", 3);

var_dump($_POST);

$action = isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : '';

if($action == 'Recalculate')  {
      RecalculateCart();
}

else if(isset($_POST['Check Out']))  {
     header("Location: "."./customer.php");
}


function RecalculateCart()  {  //  something changed, so recalculate everything

   $cart = isset($_SESSION['cart']) ? $_SESSION['cart'] : '';  //  get current cart for this session (it's not saved between browser sessions!))
   $itemcount = isset($_SESSION['itemcount']) ? $_SESSION['itemcount'] : 0;  //  get the item count
echo "itemcount from SESSION: " .$itemcount;

   for ($i=0; $i < $itemcount; $i++)  {
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity'.[$i]];  //  get quantity of new item
echo "quantity from POST: ".$quantity;

        if (empty($quantity))  {  //  quantity is 'empty' so make it zero (0))
                $quantity = 0;
        }
        else if (($quantity < 0) || (!is_numeric($quantity)))  {  //  validate it
                $quantity = 0;
        }

        $cart[QUANTITY][$i] = intval($quantity);  //  passed validation, so move it to the cart
    }

    for ($j=0; $j < $itemcount; $j++)  {

         $quantity = $cart[QUANTITY] [$j];  //  add the quantity of the new item to accumulation

   if ($quantity == 0)  {   // remove item from the cart        
        $itemcount--;
        $curitem = $j;

        while(($curitem+1) < count($cart[0]))  {

                for($k = 0; $k < 4; $k++)  {
                    $cart[$k][$curitem] = $cart[$k][$curitem+1];
                    $cart[$k] [$curitem+1]   = '';
                }
                $curitem++;     
        }
    }
 }
    $_SESSION['itemcount'] = $itemcount;  //   save the item count
    $_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;  //  save cart contents

}
?>
```

*$itemcount* is 4, according to the echo, which is correct.  *$quantity* is set in another file and becomes part of *$cart* (it's from a text field in a form; there is a submit button in that form which does the POST).  This is that code (in viewCart.php):

```
<?php

session_start();

define("PRODUCTCODE", 0);
define("PRODUCTNAME", 1);
define("QUANTITY", 2);
define("PRICE", 3);

$action = isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : '';

if (isset($_POST['productcode']))  {
  AddToCart();
}


function AddToCart()  {

$cart = isset($_SESSION['cart']) ? $_SESSION['cart'] : '';

$itemcount = isset($_SESSION['itemcount']) ? $_SESSION['itemcount'] : 0;
$cart[PRODUCTCODE][$itemcount] = $_POST['productcode'];
$cart[PRODUCTNAME][$itemcount] = $_POST['productname'];
$cart[QUANTITY][$itemcount] = intval($_POST['quantity']);
$cart[PRICE][$itemcount] = $_POST['price'];
$itemcount = $itemcount + 1;

$_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;
$_SESSION['itemcount'] = $itemcount;
echo "addToCart-itemcount: ".$itemcount;
}

?>
```

Being a somewhat of a noob at PHP, I am assuming that the POST in the first code segment is correct, except for the fact it's in another file which makes it NOT global in scope.  So does the *global* keyword apply here?  and if so, where do I put it? (in which file and which statement)?

Comment: I just skimmed your code so I'm adding this as a comment rather than an answer, but I think you're asking whether you need to do something like `global $_POST`? That not needed for the `$_POST` variable because it's what's called a "super-global": http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Comment: Oh... RATS!  I've been looking at this for 3 days now, and can't seem to figure out why nothing is in *$quantity*.  Any ideas?

Comment: I would do `var_dump($_POST);` at the top of your file to see the actual POST data that was received. The problem may be that the HTML `name` property of your input doesn't match what you have in the PHP code. In any case, if you could post your HTML that would be helpful, but I may be offline later so hopefully someone else will help.

Comment: Did the var_dump and see that once I go into Recalculate(), the quantity from POST is lost (zero)... this is the output from the var_dump and echo's.
`array(4) { ["quantity0"]=> string(1) "1" ["quantity1"]=> string(1) "2" ["quantity2"]=> string(1) "3" ["action"]=> string(11) "Recalculate" } itemcount from SESSION: 3quantity from POST: quantity from POST: quantity from POST: `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using incorrect syntax to access the quantity array item:

```
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'.[$i]];
```

The `[$i]` actually creates a new array containing the item `$i` (using the array syntax introduced in PHP 5.4), and when you try to use it as a string it gets output as just 'Array'. So it evaluates to `$_POST['quantityArray']`. If you have notices enabled you should see an "Array to string conversion" notice to help you catch this sort of thing.

So simply change it to:

```
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'.$i];
```

Or:

```
$quantity = $_POST["quantity$i"];
```

BTW, notices can be quite helpful for detecting bugs, so make sure you have them enabled. Either enable `display_errors` and `error_reporting` in php.ini or add this to your code (but make sure you only show errors on your local or development server, since reporting them on a production server can be a security risk):

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Oh my gawd!  Unbelievable!  Thank you, thank you, thank you... I really appreciate your help and suggestion about the errors... I owe you a slice of pizza!  :D

Comment: Glad that fixed it :) No need for a slice of pizza, you just helped me get to 5,000 points :)